# Recasting Python Variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python I have a variable set as a string which is a username:

```
self.loggedInUser = "Hanna"
```

When I have retrieved the user details as a list, I would like to reuse the variable:

```
self.loggedInUser = (0, "Hanna", "hash", "UID")
```

Is it possible to do this, probably the more important, is it bad practice?

H

Comment: Do you want to store the entire tuple as `self.loggedInUser` or just `"Hanna"`?

Comment: Where is the list?

Comment: The list is created in as part of another function.  I would like to store the tuple in self.loggedInUser, if that is possible?

Comment: It is possible but you sould [not do that.](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#dynamic-typing)

Comment: That is totally possible. Whether this should be recommended though, is another question. Having instance variables point to completely different data-structures during runtime seems not best-practice.

Comment: Thank you!  I will rethink my approach, I am not a developer by trade :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python lets you change the value of a variable at any time, so it's certainly possible to change the value of `self.loggedInUser` from a `string` to a `list` or `tuple`, or any other kind of object.

This can be confusing though, and could cause errors in your code if it's expecting one kind of object and finds a different kind, so it's better to split them up, say as `self.loggedInUserName` and self.loggedInUser.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, python variables can change their type.
About bad practice... There are no rules for this. Personally I think that it can cause many problems of getting a user into a function and not knowing if it is a full user or only a name. Why not a dictionary? This way the user will always be a dictionary, but unretrieved properties just won't be there.
By the way, in the line you wrote it is not a list but a tuple (tuple uses round brackets - (), list uses square ones - [])

Answer (score 0):

In Python variables are not forced as one type, variables are reference to some object and those references if changed are still references. So changing variables from one object to other is not changing this objects but references.

These operations are only on refernces:

```
variable1 = 'ala'
variable1 = []
variable1 = {}
```

These operations are on values of objects that variables are referencing too (inplace):

```
variable1 ='ala'
variable1 +='o' #variable1 -> 'alao'
```

So in Your case when changing :

```
self.loggedInUser = "Hanna"
```

to

```
self.loggedInUser = (0, "Hanna", "hash", "UID")
```

You are only working on references...

May as well do:

```
self.loggedInUser = "Hanna"
tp=type(self.loggedInUser)
if tp==str:
   self.loggedInUser = (0, self.loggedInUser, "hash", "UID")
elif tp==tuple:
   self.loggedInUser = (0, self.loggedInUser[1], "hash", "UID")
else:
   print 'sorry, something went wrong...'
```

Unused object with overwriten reference will become garbage. In Cython you could define types of variables with cdef.

Dictionaries and lists are nice too...

Here is example of auto vivication dictionary:

```
class vividict(dict):  
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

With this You could do:

```
self.loggedInUsers=vividict()

self.loggedInUsers['user0']['name']='Hanna'
self.loggedInUsers['user0']['key1']='val1'
self.loggedInUsers['user0']['key2']='val2'
self.loggedInUsers['user0']['key3']='val3'
...
```